# How to find probability of finding a particle outside the region in which it is confined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, probability, normalization

Problem:
Consider a one-dimensional particle of mass $m$ which is confined within the region $0 \le x \le a$ by a potential $V(x)$ and whose wave function is $\Psi(x, t) = \sin(\pi x/a)\exp(−i\omega t)$. What is the probability of finding the particle outside the region $0 \le x \le a$?

Approach:
I thought of finding probability inside the region $0 \le x \le a$ (by integrating $|\Psi|^2$ from $0$ to $a$) and then subtracting from 1 to give the probability of finding the particle in the remaining region.

Doubt: Wouldn't the wavefunction have to be normalised first to get the correct value of probability in the region $0 \le x \le a$? But we can't normalise it because we don't know the wave function outside the region! I was told to consider the equation to already be normalised but then I get probability as $(1-a/2)$ which has dimensions of length and has to be wrong! What is the right way of finding the probability of finding particle outside the region?

Comment: The formulation of the problem is somewhat ambiguous. One could use localization in the sense that there is a bound state such that most but not all the probability of finding a particle is concentrated in a small region. However in that case I wouldn't say that **the** wavefunction is $\Psi$, but only a part of it.

Comment: @GiorgioP I agree that the wave function given is, just a part of the complete wave function, which describes the particle in the region 0 ≤ x ≤ a. But is it possible to find probability of finding particle outside this region with only knowledge of this part?

Comment: The problem is the wrong physical dimension of the proposed $\Psi$ (which points towards an ill-formulated problem). If the claim is that it is the part of the wavefunction in the interval, we should assume that it is divided by a quantity of physical dimension lenght$^{-1/2}$ numerically equal to $1$. Then, your calculation will give the probability, provided $a<2$. But, as you see, one has to make hypotheses to transform that text into a well-defined problem.

Comment: I don’t get it.  Why is this not trivially $0$ since *by definition* cannot be found there, *i.e.* $\psi=0$ outside the region $0\le x \le a$.